# weird button image behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image, controls

I have a button which has two states; normal and in-alarm. During normal, the button looks like so:

[image: button state: normal]

and whilst in alarmed state, flashes between red and orange in a gif format, like so:

[image: button state : in alarm]  [image: button state: in alarm]

below is some snippets which decide the state of the button:

```
if (blah blah == true)
{
  ((Button)mainUI.Controls["btn" + device.deviceButtonNumber]).Image = null;
  //MessageBox.Show("Button " + device.deviceButtonNumber.ToString() + "is now flashing");
  ((Button)mainUI.Controls["btn" + device.deviceButtonNumber]).Image = Properties.Resources.red_orange;
}
else
{
  //MessageBox.Show("Button " + device.deviceButtonNumber.ToString() + "is now green");
  ((Button)mainUI.Controls["btn" + device.deviceButtonNumber]).Image = null;
  ((Button)mainUI.Controls["btn" + device.deviceButtonNumber]).BackColor = Color.Green;
}
```

The reason in the snippets i set the image to null was because i thought maybe it was stacking the images on top of each other, but this doesn't seem to have fixed it.

The problem i have is, after a while of polling devices to check the states of the buttons....the button will randomly change and look like so:

[image: Weird state]

I'm a bit stuck as to why this is happening, is seems to be varied in the amount of time before it turns to buttonstate:weird. anyone have any idea of why this is occurring?

Comment: Are we talking about a `System.Windows.Forms.Button` or a `System.Windows.Controls.Button` here?

Comment: they're System.Windows.Forms.Button buttons.

Comment: The "big red x of doom" means your control hit an exception while trying to draw.  Are you doing any custom painting with your buttons or simply toggling the image/backcolor?  Do you see any exceptions thrown?

Comment: it's in a try catch statement but isn't throwing any exceptions. i'm simply toggling between the .gif image and a backcolor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Red Cross Indicates that there is an error in Drawing the button and the red cross image is the default error image for the button.I think you have a problem in the embedded resources Check if all the images exist in the Resource and if then you might not be creating an image object.

Try to using

`((Button)mainUI.Controls["btn" + device.deviceButtonNumber]).Image = new Image(Properties.Resources.red_orange);`

Create an object from the image in the resource.Also try using an image not in the resource ie:external

Comment: i'm just going to change some logic around, and then i'll try this fix.

Comment: i think it was something along the lines of...well basically it was trying to refresh itself constantly and i think randomly it would try to refresh it's image and it hadn't finished loading the last one, so it couldn't find it. or something like that. i changed some loops around and moved some variables and it stopped looping incorrectly. and then it worked.